# ajaxQueue throws error on localhost but not on domain/server

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Problem

I have the following problem that I can't fully understand what is happening and why.
One specific page is attempting to use `$.fn.ajaxQueue` .

When I load this page on my locally (using localhost:8080) I get the error:

> TypeError: $.fn.ajaxQueue is not a function[Learn More]

When I load the deployed page (same code), I don't get the error but I get a warning:

> jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread
>   is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

### Series of Imports

The series of `<script>` statements is the same on both local and deployed.
I am noticing that the `JQuery` `<script>` tag is not firstt. **Shouldn't JQuery be the first thing that is imported???**

```
   <link href='scripts/jquery/src/skin/ui.dynatree.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/jquery.tablednd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/jQueryUtils.js"></script>
    <script src='scripts/jquery/jquery/jqueryBeforeTooltip.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='scripts/jquery/jquery/jqueryAfterTooltip.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

> `<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/src/jquery.dynatree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/plugins/ajaxautocomplete/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery/plugins/ajaxautocomplete/chosen/chosen.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

### Questions

1. Why would the error/warnings be different depending on if the server
   is localhost or another domain? Is there a logical reason or is it a
   configuration difference?
2. Is the list of imports correct? Shouldn't JQuery be first?
3. Can I add a try/catch to the statement trying to use `$.fn.ajaxQueue` and if it is `undefined`, dynamically load it and try again?

Comment: Jquery should be first. Is it the first on the server? That could explain the different javascript messages.

Comment: @Seb It's wrong on the server as well. Exact same order of imports as those I list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that there were javascript imports on a specific page that was breaking the page. After we deleted the duplicate imports, everything worked fine:

```
<script src='js/jqueryFileupload/jquery.ui.widget.js'
  type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='js/jqueryFileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js'
  type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='js/jqueryFileupload/jquery.fileupload.js'
  type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils/jQueryUtils.js"></script>
```